# Name of a maximum bound

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I'm reading [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0731070), which uses the quantity
$$\max_{x\neq0} \frac{x^T A x}{x^Tx}$$
where $A\in R^{n\times n}$ is nonsingular and $x\in R^n$.
This quantity looks so familiar to me that I'm almost certain this quantity has a special name in linear algebra... Does anyone recognize it or know its name?

Comment: The quantity inside the $\max$ is known as a Rayleigh quotient when $A$ is symmetric (Hermitian).

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat!  I presume that we could also limit our search for a maximum to the unit ball $||x||=1$, correct?

Comment: The boundary of the unit ball. (If $A = -I$, then the max would be attained at $x=0$ if you maximized over the unit ball.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire term is the [matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) of A and the objective function is the [Rayleigh quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).